# How to solve an exponential equation in Python

Tags: python, numerical-computing

Now I have an equation to solve:

exp(x * a)-exp(x * b) = c, where a,b and c are known constants.

I tried sympy and scipy.optimize.fsolve, even brenth and newton. Nothing good. I 'm new to python, like 2 weeks. So pls help me out of this. Thanks!

Comment: You could try the `numpy` package.

Comment: ```Nothing good``` does not tell us anything. Besides that, sympy and scipy.optimize are as different approaches as it gets which makes we wonder what you really want and if you know what you want.

Comment: Depending on a, b, and c there may be no solution which might be why your methods cannot find a solution.

Comment: @wrkyle there is only one solution a=b and c=0

Comment: @sascha indeed I should make it clear. First time asking question here,sry for the reluctance

Comment: @wrkyle yes it depends on the parameters, I figured this out just then. Thanks for your illustration,really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still unclear what you really want. Symbolic- vs. Numerical-optimization and exact solution vs. least-squares solution.

Ignoring this and just presenting the least-squares approach:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
import math

a = 3
b = 2
c = 1

def func(x):
    return (math.exp(x * a) - math.exp(x * b) - c)**2

res = minimize_scalar(func)
print(res.x)
print(res.fun)
```

Output:

```
0.382245085908
1.2143546318937163e-19
```

Alternative example:

```
a = 5
b = 2
c = -1
```

Output:

```
-0.305430244172
0.4546398791780655
```

That's just a demo in regards to scipy.optimize. This might not be what you want after all.

Comment: Actually I want the numerical solution, so least-squaresolution should do, thanks. For some parameters in my data set the equation has no real root so I have to change my model LOL. Thanks again for your help and illustration!